# Which the best component system of react functional or class base?

Tags: reactjs

I did not understand, which best practices of react component. That's functional base or class base. Please suggestion to me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to dig down more to get the exact knowledge of both the Components as both of them are equally important. Class based components are state based components means you can change the state (data accordingly) but in functional component you cannot do this and whatever is coming in props value you can just show that thus it is called stateless component.You should use functional components if you are writing a presentational component which doesn’t have its own state or needs to access a lifecycle hook. Otherwise you can stick to class components or take a look into the library recompose which allows you to write functional components and enhance them with a state or lifecycle hooks with HOCs!

For more:
https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108
https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/

Answer (score 0):

For simple stuff you may want to use Functional components, 
but if you want to use state and life cycle methods (component did mount, component did update, component will unmount..) you may want to use Class based components.

Although I recommend you use react hooks, because with them you can write Functional based components with state and life cycle methods - for MUCH cleaner code.

Hope this helps